# Unit testing method containing data culled from Request.Form. Newbie issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, mocking

I've asked a few questions about this, but haven't found the answer (or maybe understood what to do?).

We have an app that we are waiting to hear back from user testing. In the meantime, I was asked to create a TestProject and test out all aspects, which is something our group is trying to move towards. the app is written in C#, aspx.net.

I have most of it finished. But absolutely can't figure out how to test two aspects. I have methods that take (a)session vars, and (b)Request.Form data.

Everything I find about mocking seems to revolve around MVC architecture. The first question I asked ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082896/how-to-unit-test-method-that-creates-namevaluecollection-using-request-form-in-c)) said I should "change the method to take an HttpRequestBase". I'm not supposed to change any code whatsoever (student placement).

How can I supply the form/session data to my unit test? I can't find anything specific to this.

Sucks to be new.

Thanks!

EDIT::

Sorry, I do have Moq, but am missing something....

Here is the session code. It's only in one place (one set of tests), where as I have instances of the Request.Form in about 7 or 8....

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get the "Storage" location
    String strStorage = Path.To.Default.Storage;

    XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(Path.Combine(strStorage, "pending/") + Request.Form["thing"] + ".xml");
    Session["Files"] = "";
    foreach (XElement element in xmlDoc.Elements().Elements())
    {
        if (element.Name.ToString() != "File")
        {
            Session[element.Name.ToString()] = element.Value.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            Session["Files"] = Session["Files"] + element.Value.ToString() + ";";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using a testing framework like Rhino or Moq?

Comment: I do have Moq, but apparently can't figure out quite what the hell to do with it....

Comment: post the code that uses Session and let's see if there's anything we can do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the second answer in here about doing setups.

[How do you mock the session object collection using Moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524457/how-do-you-mock-the-session-object-collection-using-moq)

```
controllerContext.SetupGet(p => p.HttpContext.Session["test"]).Returns("Hello World");
```

See if something along those lines with Moq will get your session ones under control.  But some sample code would be helpful.  Change names and anything to keep your companies best interest in mind.